# What is faster: decode H264 1920x1080 and display it on screen 1920x1080 or decode H264 1280x720 and display 1920x1080?

Tags: flash, flv, decode, interpolation, h.264

So we are creating some video server. We broadcast flv's to our flash clients. our providers can provide us with h254 videos of 1920x1080  and 1280x720  video sizes. But that videos vill be generated from same source of 1280x720 with same bitrate. so ve will have

```
1280x720 h264 with bitRateA
and
1920x1080 with bitRateA
```

we asume we can deliver videos with same  speed.

What will be faster for clients: decode H264 1920x1080 and display it on screen 1920x1080  or decode H264 1280x720 and display 1920x1080?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that lower resolution upscaled will be faster than decoding higher resolution. Upscaling is a simple and fast operation, while h264 decoding is hella-complex (yep, that's an actual technical expression :-)).

Besides, if you're having the same bitrate on both streams you'll get no greater picture quality by increasing resolution, doubly so if you're using the same lower-res stream as a source (since there is no extra information that higher resolution stream can use). More likely, re-encoding will probably produce worse picture quality than the original lower-res stream by introducing additional dithering and quantization errors.